# Nodejs - Passport, done is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm learning passport and passport-local, using this versions:

> "passport": "^0.4.0", "passport-local": "^1.0.0"

The problem is that when try to write a user registry after get form data, receive this error message:

> (node:9120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: done is not a
>   function
>       at Strategy.passport.use.LocalStrategy [as _verify] (C:\codes\Gclimb\passport\localAuth.js:27:5)

This is the code for my localAuth.js

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const User = require('../models/user')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
    const user = await User.findById(id)
    done(null, user)
})

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true

}, async (req, username, email, password, done) => {

    const user = new User()
    user.email = email
    user.password = password
    user.username = username
    await user.save()
    done(null, user) // <----- Line 27(error)
}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing arguments less than what you are expecting

I removed the email for now, if this works, we will worry about the email

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const User = require('../models/user')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
    const user = await User.findById(id)
    done(null, user)
})

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true

}, async (req, username, password, done) => {

    const user = new User()
    user.password = password
    user.username = username
    await user.save()
    done(null, user) // <----- Line 27(error)
}))
```

Comment: Can I know what are you trying to do? Passport is meant to do authentication and not registration. Meaning it only returns back a user to you to authenticate

Answer (score 1):

Delete "req" in async. Done will work again.
I think the problem in new version of PassportJS